# C standard on negative zero (1's complement and signed magnitude)

Tags: c, standards, bit-shift, zero, negative-number

All of these functions gives the expected result on my machine. Do they all work on other platforms?

More specifically, if x has the bit representation 0xffffffff on 1's complement machines or 0x80000000 on signed magnitude machines what does the standard says about the representation of (unsigned)x ?

Also, I think the (unsigned) cast in v2, v2a, v3, v4 is redundant. Is this correct?

Assume sizeof(int) = 4 and CHAR_BIT = 8

```
int logicalrightshift_v1 (int x, int n) {

    return (unsigned)x >> n;
}

int logicalrightshift_v2 (int x, int n) {

    int msb = 0x4000000 << 1;
    return ((x & 0x7fffffff) >> n) | (x & msb ? (unsigned)0x80000000 >> n : 0);
}

int logicalrightshift_v2a (int x, int n) {

    return ((x & 0x7fffffff) >> n) | (x & (unsigned)0x80000000 ? (unsigned)0x80000000 >> n : 0);
}

int logicalrightshift_v3 (int x, int n) {

    return ((x & 0x7fffffff) >> n) | (x < 0 ? (unsigned)0x80000000 >> n : 0);
}

int logicalrightshift_v4 (int x, int n) {

    return ((x & 0x7fffffff) >> n) | (((unsigned)x & 0x80000000) >> n);
}

int logicalrightshift_v5 (int x, int n) {

    unsigned y;
    *(int *)&y = x;
    y >>= n;
    *(unsigned *)&x = y;
    return x;
}

int logicalrightshift_v6 (int x, int n) {

    unsigned y;
    memcpy (&y, &x, sizeof (x));
    y >>= n;
    memcpy (&x, &y, sizeof (x));
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just divide by (2^n) and let the compiler do the optimizing?

Comment: Assuming 2's complement: logicalrightshift (-1,1) should be 0x7fffffff, but -1 / 2 = 0

Comment: @user1016492: If your machine has `UINT_MAX` equal to `0xffffffff`, then `(unsigned)-1 >> 1` is guaranteed to be `0x7fffffff`, regardless of what representation is used for signed numbers.

Comment: @Mat: `2^n` is an exclusive or operation in C...

Comment: @Deitrich:  Perhaps that is why he did not use code markup.  Using ^ for exponentiation when typographical limitations prevent superscript is common usage.  In this case the reader has to apply context to disambiguate.  I think Mat's comment was clear enough *in context*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If x has the bit representation 0xffffffff on 1's
>   complement machines or 0x80000000 on signed magnitude machines what
>   does the standard says about the representation of (unsigned)x ?

The conversion to `unsigned` is specified in terms of *values*, not representations.  If you convert `-1` to `unsigned`, you *always* get `UINT_MAX` (so if your `unsigned` is 32 bits, you always get `4294967295`).  This happens regardless of the representation of signed numbers that your implementation uses.

Likewise, if you convert `-0` to `unsigned` then you *always* get `0`.  `-0` is numerically equal to 0.

Note that a ones complement or sign-magnitude implementation is not required to support negative zeroes; if it does not, then accessing such a representation causes the program to have undefined behaviour.

Going through your functions one-by-one:

```
int logicalrightshift_v1(int x, int n)
{
    return (unsigned)x >> n;
}
```

The result of this function for negative values of `x` will depend on `UINT_MAX`, and will further be implementation-defined if `(unsigned)x >> n` is not within the range of `int`.  For example, `logicalrightshift_v1(-1, 1)` will return the value `UINT_MAX / 2` regardless of what representation the machine uses for signed numbers.

```
int logicalrightshift_v2(int x, int n)
{
    int msb = 0x4000000 << 1;
    return ((x & 0x7fffffff) >> n) | (x & msb ? (unsigned)0x80000000 >> n : 0);
}
```

Almost everything about this is could be implementation-defined.  Assuming that you are attempting to create a value in `msb` with 1 in the sign bit and zeroes in the value bits, you cannot do this portably by use of shifts - you can use `~INT_MAX`, but this is allowed to have undefined behaviour on a sign-magnitude machine that does not allow negative zeroes, and is allowed to give an implementation-defined result on two's complement machines.

The types of `0x7fffffff` and `0x80000000` will depend on the ranges of the various types, which will affect how other values in this expression are promoted.

```
int logicalrightshift_v2a(int x, int n)
{
    return ((x & 0x7fffffff) >> n) | (x & (unsigned)0x80000000 ? (unsigned)0x80000000 >> n : 0);
}
```

If you create an `unsigned` value that is not in the range of `int` (for example, given a 32bit `int`, values > `0x7fffffff`) then the implicit conversion in the return statement produces an implementation-defined value.  The same applies to v3 and v4.

```
int logicalrightshift_v5(int x, int n)
{
    unsigned y;
    *(int *)&y = x;
    y >>= n;
    *(unsigned *)&x = y;
    return x;
}
```

This is still implementation defined, because it is unspecified whether the sign bit in the representation of `int` corresponds to a value bit or a padding bit in the representation of `unsigned`.  If it corresponds to a padding bit it could be a trap representation, in which case the behaviour is undefined.

```
int logicalrightshift_v6(int x, int n)
{
    unsigned y;
    memcpy (&y, &x, sizeof (x));
    y >>= n;
    memcpy (&x, &y, sizeof (x));
    return x;
}
```

The same comments applying to v5 apply to this.

> Also, I think the (unsigned) cast in v2, v2a, v3, v4 is redundant. Is
>   this correct?

It depends.  As a hex constant, `0x80000000` will have type `int` if that value is within the range of `int`; otherwise `unsigned` if that value is within the range of `unsigned`; otherwise `long` if that value is within the range of `long`; otherwise `unsigned long` (because that value is within the minimum allowed range of `unsigned long`).

If you wish to ensure that it has unsigned type, then suffix the constant with a `U`, to `0x80000000U`.

---

**Summary:**

1. Converting a number greater than `INT_MAX` to `int` gives an implementation-defined result (or indeed, allows an implementation-defined signal to be raised).
2. Converting an out-of-range number to `unsigned` is done by repeated addition or subtraction of `UINT_MAX + 1`, which means it depends on the mathematical *value*, not the representation.
3. Inspecting a negative `int` representation as `unsigned` is not portable (positive `int` representations are OK, though).
4. Generating a negative zero through use of bitwise operators and trying to use the resulting value is not portable.

If you want "logical shifts", then you should be using unsigned types everywhere.  The signed types are designed for dealing with algorithms where the *value* is what matters, not the representation.

Comment: @caf: I do not understand why `~INT_MAX` would give implementation define result on 2's complement. INT_MAX is an integer constant. The `~` operator flips all the the bits. Wouldn't the result be well defined even if there are padding bits? For that matter, would it also be well defined on 1's complement machines.

Comment: @user1016492: `INT_MAX` has the sign bit 0 and all the value bits 1, so `~INT_MAX` has the sign bit 1 and all the value bits 0.  This is not required to represent a normal value on 2s complement implementations, which meants that `~INT_MAX` can be out of range.  That actually makes it undefined behaviour rather than implementation defined.

Comment: Reference: 6.2.6.2/2: "implementation-deﬁned ... whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the ﬁrst two) ... is a trap representation or a normal value". "For the first two" includes two's complement, which is the second of three listed. So it's one of those cases where it is implementation-defined whether the behaviour is undefined: an implementation can do anything at all, provided it has documented that `~INT_MAX` is a trap representation. But if it documented that it's a normal value, behavior is defined. A strictly-conforming program therefore cannot use it.

Comment: @caf some clarification on aliasing: doesn't v5 fall under the category of: "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: ..., **a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object**, ..."

Comment: @user1016492: You are right, so v5 operates exactly as v6 does (I have corrected the answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the standard to the word, none of these are guaranteed to be the same on all platforms.

**In v5,** you violate strict-aliasing, which is undefined behavior.

**In v2 - v4,** you have signed right-shift, which is implementation defined. (see comments for more details)

**In v1,** you have signed to unsigned cast, which is implementation defined when the number is out of range.

EDIT:

**v6** might actually work given the following assumptions:

- 'int' is either 2's or 1's complement.
- `unsigned` and `int` are exactly the same size (in both bytes and bits, and are densely packed).
- The endian of `unsigned` matches that of `int`.
- The padding and bit-layout is the same: (See caf's comment for more details.)

Comment: isn't right shift of a signed int with non-negative value well defined ?

Comment: That's because you're dereferencing two pointers of different types that point to the same memory location. (`char*` is exempt from this)

Comment: I think you're right about the non-negative right-shift. However, the other problem is that you're assuming `int` is 32-bits. Which isn't the case on all systems.

Comment: Thanks, the assumption about 32 bit platform is added

Comment: With that assumption added, then *maybe*. I'm don't have the standard memorized or in front of me.

Comment: With regard to your assumptions in the last part, the value bits of the `int` representation are required to match up with the corresponding value bits of `unsigned`.  The only problems are that the sign bit need not correspond to another value bit in the `unsigned` representation, and any padding bits in the `int` representation can be additional value bits in the `unsigned` representation.  This means that a negative `n` could give rise to trap representaions, and a positive `n` could give an implementation-defined result.

Comment: @caf: Good point, I wrote that also assuming 'int' is either 2's or 1's complement as the OP had stated. But your point on the padding still holds. I'll edit my answer to point to your comment.

Comment: @Mysticial: Even ones' and two's complement representations have sign bits, so I'm not sure how that helps?

Comment: @caf: Hmm... If there's no padding, and the sign-bit is in the same position. Then I can't think of anymore leeway for it to not work. (maybe I'm wrong). But that's a lot of `if`s...

Comment: Yes, if there's no padding bits then that is a sufficient condition for it to work, with the result now depending only on the size of `unsigned` / `int` and what signed representation is in use.

Comment: @caf: to clarify the point about positive `n` could give an implementation-defined result, are you saying if there are padding bits, the value of these padding bits are undefined. So if they are copied verbatim to unsigned, one or more of these undefined padding bits could end up as a value bit of unsigned and therefore give an implementation defined result?

Comment: @user1016492: Yes, exactly.  You could use `& INT_MAX` to zero out those bits after the conversion, though (but this would zero out the value-bit-that-was-a-sign bit too).